# How to make primary key as foreign key in same table in Annotation Based Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

In My Hibernate Annotation based Application... i'm creating the table like this..

```
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `EC_USER` (
  `S_ID` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`CREATED_DATE` DATETIME NULL ,
`MODIFIED_BY` VARCHAR(30) NULL ,
 CONSTRAINT `CREATED_BY`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CREATED_BY` )
    REFERENCES `EC_USER` (`S_ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `MODIFIED_BY`
    FOREIGN KEY (`MODIFIED_BY` )
    REFERENCES `EC_USER` (`S_ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

So HOw to write my Hibernate Bean...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EC_USER")
public class UserVO{
@Id
@Column(name="S_ID")
private String id;
@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
private Date createdDate;
@Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
private Date modifiedDate;
}
```

So this is Correct one or any relation mapping Required...

Comment: where are your created CREATED_BY and MODIFIED_BY columns referenced above in the constraint definitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there is a CREATED_BY AND MODIFIED_BY columns you could write

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EC_USER")
public class UserVO{
@Id
@Column(name="S_ID")
private String id;
@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
private Date createdDate;
@Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
private Date modifiedDate;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="created_by")
private UserVO createdBy; 


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="modified_by")
private UserVO modifiedBy; 

}
```

Comment: It should be a ManyToOne, since many users can certainly be created or modified by another user.

Comment: While creating a Json node it goes into a cyclic fetch (UserVo fetches createdBy and then createdBy fetches UserVo again) which results in StackOverFlow. I have made fetchType eager also. But its of no use, I suppose. Do you know how to deal with it?